# Update field based on other fields of the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

I have a table `Datawarehouse` which the population went wrong. Each row has a `name` and an `ID` and for each update in the original system, a new row in the `DWH` table is created that should maintain the same `ID` and `Name` of the affected object.

For some reason there was generation of duplicate `IDs` for the same Object (same name, knowing that name is also unique object wise not table wise, same as ID, it is not a table primary key, it is just an object ID).

Knowing that I have the following fields: `ID`, `Name`, `IsLatest`, what I need to do now is to fix the Data. For that the pseudo code I need to use is:

```
 1. Select the list of rows with the same Name
 2. Select the ID where IsLatest = 1
 3. Update the rest of rows with that ID
```

I had issue with the update query, I was not able to select only one `ID`, and I was not also able to loop on different names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be completed using a correlated sub-query:

```
UPDATE DWH
SET id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM DataWarehouse
    WHERE DWH.name = name
        AND isLatest = 1
    )
FROM DataWarehouse DWH
```

Answer (score 1):

Select latest in to a temporary table & use it for updating.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourTable.ID = LatestTable.ID
FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM YourTable 
    WHERE IsLatest = 1
) AS LatestTable
WHERE YourTable.[Name] = LatestTable.[Name]
```